# Does Matthew 4:12 imply that Jesus travelled from Judea to Nazareth to Capernaum?

Tags: matthew, chronology, geography

Matthew 4:12 states:

> 12 When Jesus heard that John had been put in prison, **he withdrew to Galilee. 13 Leaving Nazareth, he went and lived in Capernaum,**

Matthew 2:19-23 states:

> Then after being warned by God in a dream, he[Joseph] left **for the regions of Galilee, and came and lived in a city called Nazareth.**

So is Nazareth in Galilee or not?  If it is, how can He withdraw to Galilee when He's already there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Nazareth is in Galilee. The confusion is cleared up rather simply

- Mt. 4:12: Jesus traveled from Judea to Galilee. In that province, he lived in the village of Nazareth, where he had grown up. Then he moved to Capernaum, a large town on the Sea of Galilee.
- Mt. 2. Joseph was living in Egypt with his family. He intend to settle in Judea but learned that the situation there was still dangerous because Herod the Great's son [Herod] Archelaus ruled there. So he went to the province of Galilee, where Herod Antipas ruled where he settled in Nazareth.

> when he heard that Archelaus was ruling over Judea in place of his
> father Herod, he was afraid to go back there. And because he had
> been warned in a dream, he departed for the region of Galilee. 23
> He went and dwelt in a town called Nazareth...

[image]

**Both passages describe Nazareth as a place within the territory of Galilee. Joseph moved from Egypt through Judea to Nazareth in Galilee; Jesus traveled from Judea to Nazareth and then Caperaum, both of the latter locations being in Galilee.**

Comment: Reading another Bible translations interpret the scripture to convey the two distinct events you're talking about. 1. Traveling to Galilee (Nazareth) then 2. Moving to Capernaum.   Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

ch3 v13 Jesus leaves Galilee to go to the Jordan, where John is (Judea proper is further south)

ch4 v1 Jesus withdraws to the wilderness close to the Jordan, possibly on the far side.

You are reading ch4 vv12-13 as a single movement. They are two movements. Wilderness to Nazareth in Galilee. Nazareth to Capernaum, still in Galilee.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Nazreth is in the region of Galilee. The problem in the question is actually referring to two different time periods.

Matthew chapter 2 deals with the events surrounding Jesus' birth, where as chapter 4 is talking about events that happened decades later.

So let's focus on the events after Jesus birth. Notice the progression of events of Matthew chapters 3-4 and John 1-4 in the following table:

| Scripture | Event | Location |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [Matthew 3:1-12](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070207/13/0) | John the Baptist is baptizing individuals | Jordan River |
| [Matthew 3:13-17](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/0/0) | Jesus is baptized | At or near Bethany across the Jordan |
| [Matthew 4:1-11](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/3/0) | Jesus is tempted by the Devil | Judean wilderness |
| [John 1:15](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/6/0), [19-51](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/6/1) | John the Baptist identifies Jesus as the Lamb of God | Bethany across the Jordan |
| [John 2:1-12](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/7/0) | Jesus first miracle at the wedding | Cana |
| [John 2:13-25](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/8/0) | Jesus cleanses the temple | Jerusalem |
| [John 3:1-21](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/9/0) | Jesus speaks with Nicodemus | Jerusalem |
| [John 3:22-36](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/10/0) | Jesus speaks with his disciples | Judean countryside |
| [Matthew 4:12](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/11/0) & [John 4:1-3](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1001070208/14/0) | Jesus leaves for Galilee | Judea |

[image: Map of Jesus' movement within Israel]
<sup>Source: [Appendix A7 "Main Events of Jesus' Earthly Life"](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/d/r1/lp-e/1001070207) in the *New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures (Study Edition)*.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the comment.  I just didn't understand why the author would say he went to Galilee by leaving Nazareth. I was conflating the 2 events as 1.

Answer (score 0):

**Example of False Topical Study** It is common for new students to erroneously combine to verses for study only because they include the same word. This type of Topical Study can lead to wrong conclusions or confusion.  Such is the case here.

The two verses quoted refer to **different** time periods and locations. (1) The Matthew 2 verse referred to Mary and Joseph leaving Egypt while Jesus was a little baby boy. They went to Nazareth to settle down and live there.

(2) The second verse in Matthew 4 referred to a much later date, after Jesus endured the Temptation in the Judaean wilderness, which was located east of Jerusalem. It was near there that John the Baptist baptized the masses of repentant Israelites in the Jordon river.

But Herod has captured John (who by thee way had pointed out Jesus as the Lamb of God, and who was to be his successor), and put him in jail. To avoid danger too, Jesus left the area and went north to the Galilee district.  But instead of staying at his **old home site**, he moved farther north to the village of Capernaum on the north shore of the Sea of Galilee.

**Recommendation** It is best to study a book in its chronological order according to chapters to avoid confusion. It is also best to study a verse in its context, regardless if the same "word" is mentioned. Different contexts may require different interpretations. Keep studying the Bible; it is food for the soul, the Bread of Life!